# How to forward JSF RI (Mojarra) log to slf4j or log4j?

Tags: java, jsf, log4j, slf4j, mojarra

How to teach [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/) to use slf4j or log4j?

According to [slf4j documentation](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html) I have to call:

```
org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
```

Somewhere in my project. But I can't call it in Mojarra... So, the question is when and how shall I execute this `install()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do it is through a custom [Listener](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm). Being initialized before JSF servlet it should configure jul-to-slf4j bridge in [`contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29).

Answer (score 0):

I believe Mojarra, being Sun code, uses java.util.logging.

The slf4j project download contains a drop-in module which forwards all j.u.l statements to slf4j.  You can then use log4j as the slf4j backend.

Comment: This is what I had to do in order to make Jersey use slf4j: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121722. Shall I do the same "hacking" with Mojarra? :(

Comment: Your question did not mention running inside junit.  Also junit tests should not depend on logging.

Comment: Well, either in junit tests or not, I still can't understand how to inject this Bridge initialization **before** Mojarra initialization...

Comment: Mojarra is a JSF 2.0 implementation, i.e. a library.  The code using the library needs to do the initialization.

Comment: Totally agree. But where this initialization can be done? Mojarra's `FacesServlet` is instantiated by JEE container, according to `web.xml` details. Is it possible to inject my own code in between?

Comment: Look at Arquillian for unit testing Java EE code.  http://www.jboss.org/arquillian