# Framework to measure spend time and memory

Tags: java, time, junit

I have to measure the time (and memory) spend in any methods of my Java project.

I have read about several method to obtain these data. I can [instrumentalized the methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180158/how-do-i-time-a-methods-execution-in-java).
I thought to use JUnit (because I have developed several test for the project). However, I read that it does [not provide the exact spend time](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/junit-benchmarks-tutorial.html), and I need a more concrete function that [using a timeout limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892125/what-is-the-best-practice-to-determine-the-execution-time-of-the-bussiness-relev). I have already used JMX in other projects, os I thought to use too.

However, I would like use a framework based on tags (like JUnit) to measure the time and the memory, but I did not find any. So, anyone know anything about this? I understand that using this way (I could have a delay).

Answer (score 1):

[JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) is a neat tool to get a really good overview. It shows you exactly what you want. There’s a trial version.
Or delivered with the JDK since version 1.6: VisualVM (jvisualvm in your JDK/bin folder). There’s also an older profiling application bundled with the JDK but it is command line only.

But none of them supports tags as far as I know. But you can filter/search at least in JProfiler.