# How to Write unit tests for this class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I need to write a unit test for this piece of code. I am just learning how to write unit tests.I want to know what are the test cases that can be written for following class specially for

```
public void delay()
```

method. it contains Thread.sleep() method.

```
 import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public abstract class AbstractDelayService<T> implements DelayService<T>
{
  private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AbstractDelayServiceTest.class);

  protected DelayFunction delayFunction;
  protected FailureCounter<T> failureCounter;

  public AbstractDelayService(DelayFunction delayFunction, FailureCounter<T> failureCouner)
  {
    this.delayFunction = delayFunction;
    this.failureCounter = failureCouner;
  }

  @Override
  public void delay()
  {
    long delay = delayFunction.getDelay();
    log.info("Delaying lookup of" + " by " + delay + " ms");

    try
    {
      Thread.sleep(delay);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void reportSendSuccess(T key)
  {
    failureCounter.reportSendSuccess(key);   
  }

  @Override
  public void reportSendFailure(T key)
  {
    failureCounter.reportSendFailure(key);    
  }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to test abstract class in Java with jUnit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569444/how-to-test-abstract-class-in-java-with-junit)

Comment: assert time difference before and after delay, within some allowed delta error ?

Comment: Pragmatic Unit Testing in Java 8 with JUnit - by Jeff Langr, with Andy Hunt and Dave Thomas. I'd recommend this book. (Kind of off topic)

Comment: Testing checks that the code produced conforms to its specification. Nobody can answer your question, because you have not told us the specification for your code.

Comment: This is not a code writing service or a test writing service.

Comment: I figured it out the answer, thanks for your concerns.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892125/what-is-the-best-practice-to-determine-the-execution-time-of-the-bussiness-relev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitively don't want to wait for real using `Thread.sleep` and then count how much time elapsed - it's slow and unreliable. You have to inject `Sleeper` interface to tested class, so you can mock i in tests. For example:

```
interface Sleeper {
    void sleep(long ms) throws InterruptedException;
}
```

...

```
class RealSleeper implements Sleeper {
    void sleep(long ms) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(ms);
    }
}
```

...

```
private long time = 0;

@Test
public void test() {
    AbstractDelayService service = new AbstractDelayService(new Sleeper(){
        void sleep(long ms) {
            time+=ms;
        }, delayFunction, failureCouner){};
    Assert.assertEquals(time, 0);
    service.delay();
    Assert.assertEquals(time, 1000);
}
```

This way you can verify your class sleeps exactly as long as it's supposed to.
You will still need some integration tests to make sure `Thread.sleep` is actually invoked - but you don't have to sleep long in such tests and you don't need to measure the exact timings.