# How the JUnit test spent time is computed in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm developing some JUnit tests for my application.

When I run the tests in Eclipse I get the result for each test and the time spent, as you can see in the image below.

[image]

But how is it computed? 
Does it include the time spent in the @Before and @After methods for each test or does it take into account only the time spent in the @Test method?

Thank you

Comment: Why not test it out? In methods annotated with `@Before` or `@After`, execute a long running task, see if it affects the results.

Comment: eclipse is not computing anything.  The junit test runner is performing the computations.  it seems likely that the `@Before` and `@After` methods are not included in the duration of a given test.

Comment: I added a Thread.sleep(5000); in the Before method and the final time of the test is more than 7 seconds. I think that this means that the spent time takes into account also the Before and After methods...isn't it?

Comment: Use also System.currentTimeMillis() at the begining and at the end of your test method (excluding @Before and @After) if you want to know exactly the time spent by your test

Comment: Or maybe the Stopwatches http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892125/what-is-the-best-practice-to-determine-the-execution-time-of-the-bussiness-relev

Answer (score 0):

There is, in JUnit, intreface called `TestListener`. JUnit provides some implementations that were attached to each test run. One of those implementations is internal `Listener` class in `Result` class. It calculates time in that way

```
public void testRunStarted(Description description) throws Exception {
    startTime.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
}

@Override
public void testRunFinished(Result result) throws Exception {
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    runTime.addAndGet(endTime - startTime.get());
}
```

Code taken from `org.junit.runner.Result` JUnit 4.12.

After calculation JUnit publish "report" that contains all `Result`s of tests. IDEs like Eclipse or Idea attach to test JUnit they implementations of `TestListener` that could parse&show "report". Finally listeners from IDE send message to IDE window and you could see test result and time.