# What kind of logging is Jersey using and how to intercept it with Logback?

Tags: java, logging, jersey, logback

I would like to intercept Jersey's logging with Logback, but I'm not sure how. Could somebody please give some pointers?

Comment: Are you using slf4j? Is it jersey on the client side or on the server side within an application server?

Comment: I did this with jetty the other day using logback/slf4j. Dropping in the slfj bridging jars fro JUL, commons logging and log4j means you'll catch almost everything and can configure it from one logback config file.

Comment: @assylias: It's both on the client and server side.

Comment: On the client side you can use a bridge or if you don't mind a little hack: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26103488/829571

Comment: jersey uses java util logging. put the jul-to-sl4fj bridge on your classpath.
See http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jersey logs to `java.utils` logging (JUL). You can redirect JUL logging to SLF4J with the [jul-to-slf4j](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j) bridge. To achieve this, add `org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j` as a dependency to your project. If you use Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

To initialize the bridge, invoke `SLF4JBridgeHandler.install()` during the initialization of your application.

This will however not remove any handlers from JUL's root logger, typically resulting in duplicated log output (since JUL still produces output). To remove the JUL handlers invoke `SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger()`.

These invocations can for example be done in the application's main method or a static initializer block of your main class.

```
static {
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
}
```

The bridge will only receive logs that the JUL loggers actually process (based on log level). To give Logback full control over log selection we need to make sure all log levels are processed by JUL, so that all logs reach the Logback loggers. This is done by setting the JUL loggers to the lowest possible log level:

```
static {
    java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("global").setLevel(Level.FINEST);
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
}
```

This does mean that *all* logs will be processed by the JUL loggers and the bridge, leading to a considerable performance hit. Logback has a solution for this: by adding the [`LevelChangePropagator`](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#LevelChangePropagator) context listener, Logback's log levels will be propagated to JUL's loggers. `LevelChangePropagator` can also perform the reset of JUL's log manager from the previous code block. To configure all this, add the following to your `logback.xml`:

```
<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
  <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
</contextListener>
```

With this configuration you can go for the first initialization block in this answer, since the first two statements of the second block are now handled by the context listener. To be precise, there's actually a small difference: the `LogManager.reset()` method resets all log levels and removes all handlers except from the root logger, while the "resetJUL" option on the context listener only resets the log levels.

To summarize:

1. add `jul-to-slf4j` dependency
2. add initialization code (the first variant from this answer)
3. add `LevelChangePropagator` context listener to your Logback configuration